# Create generic task, not an approval one with SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I cannot figure out how to create a generic workflow task with SharePoint Designer 2013. I selected the action "Start a task process" and I tried executing my workflow but it creates only an approval task. In my case I need to create a generic task.